# box_dir_create() function from boxr package is not creating a folder in Box

Tags: r, box, file-sharing

I've been having difficulty getting boxr to successfully create a file within my box directory. My code reads:

```
library(boxr)
box_auth()

my_file_dir <- box_setwd("76009318507")

box_dir_create(dir_name="TEST", parent_dir_id = my_file_dir)
```

after running which, I get the following output:

```
box.com remote folder reference

 name        : 
 dir id      : 
 size        :  
 modified at :  
 created at  :  
 uploaded by : 
 owned by    : 
 shared link : None 

 parent folder name :  
 parent folder id   :
```

Checking my box directory, I find no folders have been created.

I've tried using additional arguments within box_dir_create, but according to the documentation only dir_name and parent_dir_name are accepted.

Any help is much appreciated. I understand this is a somewhat obscure R package, so I've included links to the documentation below:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/boxr/boxr.pdf
https://github.com/r-box/boxr

Comment: I would have expected that `box_auth` would need some argument values.

Answer (score 1):

I got an answer via the package's developer, and I figured I'd pay it forward for any fellow travelers in the future.

It turns out that `box_setwd()` sets a default directory but returns nothing. Using

```
box_dir_create(dir_name="TEST", parent_dir_id = "76009318507")
```

creates the folder successfully. It will not do so if a folder of the same name is already created.

After more digging, I was also told that `box_dir_create()` is quietly passing back a lot of useful information, including the newly created directory's ID. To access it you can save the function results as a variable, like so:

```
b <- box_dir_create("test_dir")

names(b) # lots of info

b$id # what you want

box_ul(b$id, "image_file.jpg") # is this file by file?
box_push(b$id, "image_directory/") # or a directory wide operation?
```

Thanks for your help, and I hope this helps someone else down the road. Cheers!